# Share database between app and web

Tags: php, android, database, sqlite, shared

I'm involved into an app that have to retrieve queries from an existing database. This db have to be implemented in php in a remote server, and will be the place where the admin will have to insert content into the shared db, but I don't know how to implement that correctly or what is the best solution.

I'm thinking about make a sqlite database with php and connect directly the app to the db, but I haven't found yet the best way to do that.

What do you think? Thank guys.

Comment: Do you mean that an PHP Project and an App must work with the Data in the database?

Comment: Yes. An admin will manage the web and will insert data, and the app will make queries to the database,

Comment: @KingOfMasses Answer is the correct way to do it

Comment: Are you asking which database to use? If you're not sure just use the easiest datebase for you to use. Even CSV files if that suits your needs. If you want more information you need eplain what type of data you're storing.

Comment: Mostly strings, I'll look into KingOfMasses reply, and probably I'll use MySql. My doubt was if I can connect directly the app with a sqlite database made in php, but I see that it isn't the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, without any server communication ([Web services](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp)) you can't use the website database in android application.

If you want to manage the communication between the website and the android app means you need a centralized server (probably my sql dab) which having the data of your web/mobile applications. So, after that by using the web service methods (REST/SOAP) you can achieve the communication between them

> I'm thinking about make a sqlite database with php and connect
>   directly the app to the db, but I haven't found yet the best way to do
>   that.

This is not the right approach to connect mobile applications with the database. Instead you should create a middleware(REST/SOAP webservice) which runs on server. This middleware will in turn connect with the database and your mobile app whether it is android, iOS or windows app can communicate with this middleware.

Comment: Yes, of course I know I need a centralized server. I'll look into REST/SOAP then. Thanks.